# Razor: If model is List<> then @Html.LabelFor creates empty "for" field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

If the model is a list of objects then `@Html.LabelFor model => model[i].member)` creates an empty `for` attribute. 
The DisplayName works properly, model binding also works just fine. The only thing that does not work is the `for` attribute.

Below there are two versions of the MVC code. The first 3 code snippets are for the model, controller and view combination that does not work, (the model is a list). The second set of 3 code snippets work. This time the list is wrapped in an object.

What am I missing?

Model:

```
public class ViewModel {
    public bool ClickMe { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult LabelForViewModel() {
    List<ViewModel> model = new List<ViewModel>() {
        new ViewModel() { ClickMe = true}
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

View:

```
@model List<ModelBinding.Models.ViewModel>
// form code removed for brevity
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) {
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model[i].ClickMe)
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].ClickMe, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].ClickMe, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Markup:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">ClickMe</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input name="[0].ClickMe" class="form-control check-box" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" data-val-required="The ClickMe field is required." data-val="true"><input name="[0].ClickMe" type="hidden" value="false">
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="[0].ClickMe"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please notice that the for field is empty and the input has no id field (that one is used in the "for" field).

I have created a wrapper model that contains a list of objects, modified the controller and view and then it works just fine. In this case the "for" field is filled in correctly and everything works as expected.

```
public class ListWrapper {
    public List<ViewModel> ViewModels { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.ViewModels.Count; i++) {
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ViewModels[i].ClickMe)
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ViewModels[i].ClickMe, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ViewModels[i].ClickMe, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Markup:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="ViewModels_0__ClickMe">ClickMe</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input name="ViewModels[0].ClickMe" class="form-control check-box" id="ViewModels_0__ClickMe" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" data-val-required="The ClickMe field is required." data-val="true"><input name="ViewModels[0].ClickMe" type="hidden" value="false">
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="ViewModels[0].ClickMe"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, it seems that the `for` attribute is empty only if the model is a list of objects.

Is this a known issue? Or maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is the result of the framework complying with HTML-4 specifications. In HTML-4

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

When your model is a collection and you use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].SomeProperty)` to generate form controls, the method generates `name` and `id` attributes based on the name of the property. In this case the `name` attribute for the first item in the collection will be

```
name="[0].SomeProperty"
```

but to avoid clashes with jQuery selectors, the method replaces `.`, `[`, and `]` characters with an underscore `_` when generating the `id` attribute which would result in

```
id="_0__SomeProperty"
```

but because this is invalid according to the HTML-4 specification, the helper does not output it in the html.

The same applies when using `@Html.LabelFor()` (since the associated form control will not have an `id` attribute, the value of the `for` attribute is not output in the html.

Note that in HTML-5, the `id` attribute would be valid, so hopefully this behavior will be dropped in the future.

Your second example works because `id="ViewModels_0__ClickMe`" begins with a letter and is therefore valid.

Side note: You could solve the first issue by generating your own `id` attributes, for example

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model[i].ClickMe, new { for = string.Format("item{0}", i) })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ViewModels[i].ClickMe, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = string.Format("item{0}", i) } })
```

Comment: @GabrielLuci, The model does not contain a property named `Item` so this would not work and could never bind to anything

Comment: Yeah, I realize that now. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp) describes an `Item` property, but it's only exposed via the indexer.

Comment: Using Linq, he could use `Model.ElementAt[i].ClickMe`. That would probably generate an ID like `"ElementAt_0__ClickMe"`, maybe? Using Linq here is probably not ideal though.

Comment: @GabrielLuci. No that will not work either. It will not generate the correct `name` attribute necessary for model binding (and the `for` attribute in the label will still be empty anyway). I have edited my answer to show how it can be done (the other alternative is to wrap the form control in a `<label>` element

Answer (score 0):

The @model declaration assigns the model object to the `Model` variable (note the captial 'M'). But then you are reading from `model`, which hasn't been assigned.

Try this:

```
  @model List<ModelBinding.Models.ViewModel>
  // form code removed for brevity
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => Model[i].ClickMe)
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model[i].ClickMe, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model[i].ClickMe, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

That doesn't explain why your second example works at all, but hey, give this a try.