# ASPNET MVC 5 Html helper Action method view results input id missing (sometimes..) Possible Bug?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

To recreate the issue I'm having I've set up two simple controller actions, two views and a view model:

**MultiForms Action (in the form controller class)**

```
public class FormController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult MultiForms()
    {
        return View("MultiForms");
    }

    // ...
```

**MultiForms.cshtml - Razor View**

```
@Html.Action("MyFormGet", "Form")
```

Notice in the action method I call the controller method that returns the form partial view.

**MyFormGet Action**

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult MyFormGet()
{
    var viewModel = new MyFormViewModel();
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "_");
    return PartialView("MyForm", viewModel);
}
```

**View Model**

```
public class MyFormViewModel
{
    public string TextInput1 { get; set; }
}
```

**MyForm.cshtml - Razor View**

```
@model Mvc5App.Controllers.MyFormViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("MyFormPost", "Form", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TextInput1)
}
```

When I point my browser at `/Form/MultiForms` I get the output I expect:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="e166fa0d_46fe_40d4_a970_73c52a35f224.TextInput1" id="e166fa0d_46fe_40d4_a970_73c52a35f224_TextInput1">
```

Then I refresh the page and the output becomes this:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="48edc339_69ad_4b9b_9583_198038beab45.TextInput1">
```

Where did the id attribute go? Is this a bug in ASPNET MVC5 or have I done something wrong with this setup?

Comment: What do you mean by "Main Controller Razor View"? What action method does `/Form/MultiForms` point to, since there is no `FormController`? Why are you creating a view model instance in your `MyFormGet()` method, but not using this instance anywhere?

Comment: The MultiForms controller returns MultiForms.cshtml. The only line in this view is an Action helper method that calls the MyFormGet controller and returns the MyForm.cshtml view. The MyFormGet controller returns an instance of MyFormViewModel with one property that renders the form with a single input. I think you're missing the main issue: **the field should render with an id attribute and it doesn't (sometimes)**

Comment: If your controller has name `MultiForms` then endpoint `/Form/MultiForms` is invalid...

Comment: I've added the controller class FormController that extends Controller. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: But looks like you aren't actually passing a view model instance when creating the partial view.

Comment: I've edited it to pass the viewModel instance. My mistake. If you can recreate and the **id attribute** always renders, please let me know.

Comment: You can always pass in the id attribute too. `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TextInput1, new {id = "whatever"})`. Anyway I doubt you want a GUID id.

Comment: So, it's fine with you that sometimes the id will render and sometimes the id doesn't render? This is a simple example of the issue where the id doesn't render, what I actually need to do is more complex and won't work(easily) with hardcoded ids. Is this a known bug in .NET MVC?

Comment: `Id` isn't rendered only if you try to set `HtmlFieldPrefix`...

Comment: @demo, you're right. But I need that if there are multiple forms on the same page that have inputs with the same id/name... I'll try looking into an alternative to that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @[demo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3917754/demo) I think I figured out when the id doesn't show up...

If the id starts with a digit(or underscore) it will not render. So this GUID will render:

`f3b1a447_3786_4472_9dfe_14c3ae8aae24`

But this one will not:

`1c26ce3d_5c71_408a_aae2_7be414f1d383`

The solution for the above seems to be prefixing with something like this:

`FOO_1c26ce3d_5c71_408a_aae2_7be414f1d383`

And the problems go away.

Comment: For a bit more detail as to why this is the default behavior, refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36552762/razor-if-model-is-list-then-html-labelfor-creates-emtpy-for-field/36560528#36560528)