# ASP.NET MVC EditorForModel ID Naming

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC 5, I'm using `EditorForModel` and an `EditorTemplate` to show `IEnumerable` data from my model in a table where the user can edit it. ASP.NET MVC seems to name the id fields for the controls in the format `'<row number>.<model property>'`.

For example, a checkbox control `@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model.Bold...` on the 4th row of the table ends up with an id of `[3].BoldText`.

When I try to use JQuery to get the value of that control using the selector `$('#[3].BoldText')`, JQuery throws an error I suspect because of the [ or period.  Is there any way to set the naming format using EditorForModel?

Alternately, is there a way I can get the value of that checkbox in Javascript using an id in that format?

I've tried the following none of which work...

```
$('#[3].BoldText')
$("input[id='[3].BoldText']")
document.getElementById('[3].BoldText')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code would not be generating any `id` attribute - what you are seeing is the `name` attribute. By default, the `HtmlHelpers` replace the `.`, `[` and `]` characters from the `name` with a `_` (underscore). But because of compliance with HTML-4 specifications, that would be invalid, therefore the `id` attribute is omitted.

For a detailed explanation, refer [Razor: If model is List<> then @Html.LabelFor creates empty “for” field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36552762/razor-if-model-is-list-then-html-labelfor-creates-empty-for-field/36560528#36560528).

You can change the selector to use the `name` attribute

```
$("input[name='[3].BoldText']")
```

Alternatively, use a view model containing your collection property, and an `EditorTemplate` or a `for` loop to generate the html so that your html would look like (assumes the property is named `Items`)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Items[0].BoldText" id="Items_0__BoldText" ... />
```

so that you can then use the `id` selector

```
$('#Items_0__BoldText')
```

Comment: Completely missed the id not being rendered so yeah, the name attribute works.  Great answer!  Thanks.